# How to limit the decimals in the final string of this equation

Tags: swift

How do I ensure that there are only 2 decimal places for this equation (which is converted into a string) in swift.

```
let avocadoE = ((Double(proteinIntake)!/4.73) * (1/Double(list.count)))

let avocadoP = String(avocadoE)
```

The values proteinIntake and lis.count are already defined in my code.
I can't seem to find any solutions online.

Comment: You are better off using a `NumberFormatter` to get the proper, localized result. None of the answers in the duplicate do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this 
`let avocadoP = String(format: "%.02f", avocadoE)`